# How is automatic image optimization performed?

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

How is automatic image optimization performed? I'm looking for a general understanding or areas where I can read more into this, for example with the top image the bottom was automatically optimized using an image optimizing service within a few seconds.

In this example the saturation, brightness, hue and various other parameters are changed.

Original:

[image: original]

Optimized:

[image: optimized]

Comment: I would recommend [literature review](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literature_review).

Comment: As a start, you can look into global auto level and auto gamma adjustments. Or research adaptive similar methods. Often such changes you observe are achieve by these methods separately on each channel. Also look into white balancing or gray-world balancing

Comment: What service (URL) did you use to optimize the example?

Answer (score 1):

One possible method to produce a similar result is to convert to LAB colorspace, stretch the hisogram to full dynamic range separately for the L channel and the A and B channels (the same), then convert back to (s)RGB colorspace.

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice! And maybe a little sharpening in the L channel?